# encoding typescript lib "solana/buffer-layout"

Tags: typescript, solana

error when I try to encode scheme from solana contract

```
const settingsSchema = lo.struct([
    lo.ns64("cost"),
    lo.u32("width"),
    lo.u32("height"),
    lo.u16("max_players"),
])
```

error message: `Type 'UInt' is not assignable to type 'Layout<never>'`
`Type 'NearInt64' is not assignable to type 'Layout<never>'`
`Type 'Sequence<number>' is not assignable to type 'Layout<never>'`

Answer (score 2):

If you're in TypeScript, the `buffer-layout` package requires that you provide a type for the `struct` that you're creating.  In your case, you can change this to:

```
const lo = require('@solana/buffer-layout');
interface Settings {
    cost: bigint,
    width: number,
    height: number,
    max_players: number,
}
const settingsSchema = lo.struct<Settings>([
    lo.ns64("cost"),
    lo.u32("width"),
    lo.u32("height"),
    lo.u16("max_players"),
])
```

Comment: This answer seems to be in the right direction, but needs some extra info, e.g., how do you import the types?  Is there a pointer to the solana documentation or other source?

Comment: It looks like the asker was just using `lo` as the imported `@solana/buffer-layout` package, as it's used in the examples of the repo https://github.com/solana-labs/buffer-layout#examples -- I updated the code to add the import line